# Discord.py sending an embed without the use of add fields

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to get a message from a user, and then sending it to a specific text channel. The message shall be in an embed. But I don't like how it looks when you have a bunch of fields, I would like the description in the `discord.Embed()` to hold the text content. But it is giving me an error
`TypeError: Object of type Message is not JSON serializable`

This is my code:

```
class Changelog(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Changelog is loaded')

    @commands.command()
    async def changelog(self, ctx):
        changelog_channel = self.client.get_channel(759547196433104956)
        await ctx.send("`Message: `")
        message = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author, timeout=300)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Changelog", description=message, color=0)
        await changelog_channel.send(embed=embed)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Changelog(client))
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're getting this error in the code that you showed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not getting this error because you're not adding fields, but because you're trying to put a `message` instance in the description, while you should be putting that message's `content` in there instead. The description can only take `strings` as it's value.

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="Changelog", description=message.content, color=0)
```

`wait_for("message")` returns a `discord.Message` instance. A `Message` holds that message's content, id, author, channel, and way more inside. If you only want to get the text the user sent, you need the `content` attribute.

More info on what a `Message` can do can be found in the [API docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message).